# Alternative to a coefficient of variation

Tags: regression-coefficients, coefficient-of-variation

I am currently collecting data 4x per week with a fencing athlete. She jumps with each foot on a separate force plate, so we can see asymmetries in force curves. We noticed that whenever she is more fatigued, the asymmetry between both legs increases. Being a fencer, she is consistently stronger off of one leg, so the results always indicate a bias to her right leg, but it can change from 20% to 35% difference.

Based off of this, I wanted to calculate the coefficient of variation with the idea that whenever there is a daily change that is bigger than the CV, then I can reliably say she is fatigued, and training should be modified to take her fatigue into account.

The problem is that the scale we use is an interval scale, not a ratio scale. Essentially, positive numbers indicate a bias to her right leg, and negative numbers indicate a bias to her left leg. To be fair, she has never shown a bias to her left, but technically it is possible. Zero does represent an absence of asymmetry, but negative numbers can exist and do represent something.

So my question is, with the goals that I have, what descriptive parameter should I use to accomplish my goals?

Comment: FYI, there are other metrics that we track on top of asymmetry, and those ARE ratio scales. I assume CV makes sense in these situations, though I also guess that ideally, if I could use just one parameter for all of my variables, it'd be better. I am open to any ideas!

Comment: I don't see that the coefficient of variation is where you should start even when well defined. It seems that you start with two measurements, left leg and right leg. I'd plot difference versus mean of legs etc. Perhaps even the difference is the wrong place to start if there is extra structure in the data. Perhaps the ratio makes more sense.  Otherwise put, I don't think you can get good advice before we know more about the data. Generally also, it is sometimes right but often wrong to assume that there is, or should be, a simple reduction of data that will capture all signal and no noise.

Answer (score 0):

%CV gives you an idea of how consistent a set of data looks, so you figure you can find some sort of fatigue "threshold" if you look at the %CV of the differences in the force curve data you get.  Is that right?  If so I imagine there are simpler ways to look at it.  Just throwing an idea out here, but if you quantify the asymmetry as a percentage of the right foot (right-left)/right, you should be able to say for example, percentage differences <40% (when the asymmetry breaks down and the force of each leg become more equal) your fencer is fatigued.  Your data should show some sort of rise in left leg bias that might correlate with some of the other metrics you also measure.  I don't know, just a thought.